# Find the point where the line intersects the surface

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Consider the normal line to the surface $z = x^2 +y^2$ (paraboloid) at the point P(1,1,2). Find the point where the line intersects the surface a second time.

I never learned. How do I solve this?

Comment: 1. Differentiate; 2. Substitute (1,1,2) to get a plane equation; 3. Using (1,1,2) and the perpendicular transformation get a 3d line equation; 4. Treat the paraboloid and line equations as simultaneous and solve.

Comment: differentiate with respect to what?

Comment: You're dealing with partial derivatives. Hold y constant and differentiate WRT x and then hold x constant and differentiate WRT y. Any two lines that pass through a point in 3d space define a plane, and there is only one line perpendicular to that plane through that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not ask for a solution, so i will answer your question:
Let $f\left(x,y,z\right):=x^2+y^2-z$. The parabolloid is $A:=\left\{\left(x,y,z\right) : f\left(x,y,z\right)=0\right\}$. Thus for $P=(x_P,y_P,z_P)\in A$ the Normal $n_P$ of $A$ in $P$ is the Gradient $\nabla f\left(x_P,y_P,z_P\right)$. Now consider $g_{P}\left(t\right):=P+t\cdot n_{P}$ and find all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $0=f\left(g_{P}\left(t\right)\right)$.